# Multithreading java optimization

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

In my program I try tro grasp how to use ExecutorService to optimize my program. 
For some reason, It gets stuck a little on two Urls. The http://sjsu.edu/ and https://paypal.com. When it sits on these two, it does not continue executing other URLS.

Should the other 3 threads available not continue even though the two domains aren't responsing fast enough?

How is this fixed in the best possible manner?

```
public class SequentialPinger {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String[] hostList = {"http://crunchify.com", "http://yahoo.com",
            "http://www.ebay.com", "http://google.com",
            "http://www.example.co", "https://paypal.com",
            "http://bing.com/", "http://techcrunch.com/",
            "http://mashable.com/", "http://thenextweb.com/",
            "http://wordpress.com/", "http://cphbusiness.dk/",
            "http://example.com/", "http://sjsu.edu/",
            "http://ebay.co.uk/", "http://google.co.uk/",
            "http://www.wikipedia.org/",
            "http://dr.dk", "http://pol.dk", "https://www.google.dk",
            "http://phoronix.com", "http://www.webupd8.org/",
            "https://studypoint-plaul.rhcloud.com/", "http://stackoverflow.com",
            "http://docs.oracle.com", "https://fronter.com",
            "http://imgur.com/", "http://www.imagemagick.org"
        };

        List<CallableImpl> callList = new ArrayList();
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        for (String url : hostList) {
            CallableImpl callable = new CallableImpl(url);
            callList.add(callable);
        }
        for (CallableImpl callableImpl : callList) {
            System.out.println("Trying to connect to: " + callableImpl.getUrl());
            Future<String> lol = es.submit(callableImpl);
            System.out.println("status: " + lol.get());
        }

        es.shutdown();

    }
}
```

My Callable implementation

```
public class CallableImpl implements Callable<String> {

    private final String url;

    public CallableImpl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() {
        String result = "Error";

        try {
            URL siteURL = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) siteURL
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            connection.connect();

            int code = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (code == 200) {
                result = "Green";
            }

            if (code == 301) {
                result = "Redirect";
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            result = "->Red<-";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: calling get on the future right after you submit it turns this into a blocking call, so it stops you from submitting more tasks until the current future completes.

Comment: From the documentation: *Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result* - So you are basically waiting after submitting each task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code you submit `Callable` to `ExecutorService` one by one and immediately call `Future.get()` which will block until result is ready (or exception is thrown at runtime).

You'd better wrap `ExecutorService` with `CompletionSerivce` which provides results as soon as they are ready. And split for-loop into two loops: one to submit all `Callable`s and second to check results.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
ExecutorCompletionService<String> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(es);

for (CallableImpl callableImpl : callList) {
        System.out.println("Trying to connect to: " + callableImpl.getUrl());
        completionService.submit(callableImpl);
}
for (int i = 0; i < callList.size(); ++i) {
    completionService.take().get();   //fetch next finished Future and check its result
}
```

Comment: I have looked the ExecutorCompletionService class up, and it seems to be too difficult for me to grasp with my current knowledge of multithreading. Do you mind to specify a bit further?

Comment: @JonasGrønbek each call to `ExecutorCompletionService.take()` either returns `Future` that already finished (either normally or with exception) or blocks until such `Future` is available. So if you submitted 10 tasks to `CompletionService` you need to call `take()` 10 times to get all results. Results are returned from `take()` as soon as they are available and this might not be the order in which they were submitted

Comment: So it is correct to say that when submitting with a ExecutorCompletionService, it stores the Future and the threads looks for the next task.
When calling take(). You ask if it has any futures stored, and waits until a thread completes something if it is currently empty? @Ivan

Comment: It starts executing task as usual `ExecutoService` but also stores finished futures internally and when `take()` is called it checks if there are finished futures

Comment: Thanks a ton! @Ivan

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

You call `get()` on the `Future` directly after creating it, blocking the main thread. Thus you don't have any parallel calls at all, and making the `ExecutorService` essentially useless. Your code is equivalent to simply calling `callableImpl.call()` yourself.

**Solution**

Don't call `get()` if you want to continue execution and have each `CallableImpl` run in parallel. Instead you can call `es.awaitTermination()` after `es.shutdown()`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) added in Java 8 and add a callback to it.

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(myCallable::call, es)
        .thenAccept(result -> {
            something(result);
        });
```

I would suggest making your Callable be a Supplier to make this simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote: "it does not continue executing other URLS" - I believe it does, but your log messages are misleading because are not tightly connected to the actual execution. To fix this, do the following:

1. Move `System.out.println("Trying to connect to: ")` and          `System.out.println("status: ")` into the `CallableImpl.call()` method.
2. Do not call to `lol.get()` at all.

This way you will see actual sequence of the start and the end of handling each URL.